# Getting unexpected syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

Trying to create a form and took this from a tutorial site...It looks to me I have the correct number of brackets. Should there be less? Can't figure out this error.

**syntax error, unexpected '{' ../contact.php on line 68**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Bunch'; 
    $to = 'me@hotmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hi There!';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {           
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

You've got two `else` clauses, which is a syntax error.

```
if (...) {
  ...
} else if (...) { 
   ...
} else if (...) {
  ...
} else {  <--only ONE allowed
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Marc B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884205/28071) nailed it, but I think  you were going for something like this:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {           
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { # from "if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {"
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    } else { # from "if ($name != '' && $email != '') {"
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Took one of them out and it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($name != '' && $email != '') {           
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }

    }
```

to

```
if ($name != '' && $email != '') {           
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 

    }else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
```